# Outputting a PDO request from mySQL into a selector list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to know how I can insert data from MySQL into a "selector" with "options" using PHP PDO

My table is "Gender" have two columns, gender_id & gender

```
<?php
     include_once 'dbConfig.php';
     $stmt2 = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Gender");
     $stmt2->execute();
     $data = $stmt2->fetchAll();
      ?>
     <select class="form-control input-sm" name="Departamento" id="Sel1" type="text">
        <?php
        foreach($data as $row){
          echo "<option value='".$row['gender_id']."'>".$row['gender']."</option>";
        }
         ?>
     </select>
```

My connection to DB is working well, but "Select" Not show my data coming from my database

I ask for your help, for your attention and time THANK YOU!

Comment: Is `$data` populated?

Comment: If this is a real situation, direct input is easier: <option value='M'>Male</option> ... ?

Comment: You may be safe assuming only 3 or 4 genders. Not sure I would have a select for it.

Comment: What you spend is that I will use the select on other things , so I wanted to know how to apply it is in the other select I have to do , which is more complicated